# Xcode is not archiving to the specified version number

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store

This is what my Xcode screen looks like before archiving

[image]

This is what shows up in the Organizer after archiving:

[image]

I recently had done an upgrade to my Mac which I think was because of iOS 14.  Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Did you clean your build folder before archiving ?

Comment: just did that and it didn't change anything

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I don't know why, but I also had this problem after the xcode 14 version update.

In my case, it was solved by modifying the version in the "Info" tab without changing the version in the "General" tab in xcode settings.

<Custom iOS Target properties on "Info" tab>

- Bundle version string (short) <<< version
- Bundle version <<< build number

Comment: I also had the same issue after the update and this seems to work. Have they really broken the general tab? Wow

Comment: God bless ya All! It saved my day!

Comment: Worked for me as well! Apple really hates us developers...

Comment: This issue happened to me because I changed my device and took the code from a backup drive.

Comment: those who are looking for watch only app, refer this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75624890/1658037

Answer (score 62):

open info.plist to source

and change this

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
```

Comment: And if you use fastlane for version updating???

Comment: When I do this and archive, my app shows up under `Other Items` in the `Organizer`.

Comment: I am using flutter and this one's work well

Answer (score 14):

Go to the explorer, open your project (Base Application here), find the file info, click it, the file will open in the explorer.

For the `Bundle version string (short): $(MARKETING_VERSION)`

For `Bundle version: $(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`

[image: Info.plist version upgrade setting]

Then change the version here:
[image: Changing the version in the application target]

This should work, but if it doesn't work, you can specify your version number directly as:

`Bundle version string (short): 2.0.0` (this is your version number)

And build number as:

For `Bundle version: 1` (this is your build number)

Also note, you can even open the file with the external editor and change your configurations there [image: Opening the info.plist with external editors]

Hope this helped.

Comment: very detailed.....

Answer (score 13):

Open Info.plist file in Xcode and update value column by `$(MARKETING_VERSION)` in Bundle version string (short) section and `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)` in `Bundle version` section.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For a watch-only app, select the `iOS` target and update the value in `Build Settings -> Versioning -> Marketing Version`.

Comment: Changing the version for the iOS target worked for me, although I consider it a workaround and not a fix ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

You might have a build settings named `GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE` is set to `YES`. This can cause your current Info.plist file overriden by current Xcode Build settings , try to set `GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE` to `NO`.

Answer (score 2):

On XCode 14.2 and possibly earlier, there's a chance that if you're setting the new version number and immediately Archive, XCode won't update the `VERSION` variables fast enough and leave you with the older ones. You can either set them right away on the Info.plist file, or press enter and move around the IDE screens a bit before hitting Archive. It's an UX/UI problem foremost.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're coming from a flutter project this is managed by the `version` attribute in pubspec.yaml, documentation states this:

```
# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.

version: 1.0.0+1
```

Comment: Then you need to run `flutter run` for the changes to apply

Answer (score 1):

My project is developed using Flutter and here is the info.plist content:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

Based on @user20054411 answer, change to:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the new modified version successfully on your device once.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue (a Watch-only app) by changing the version and build numbers in both the top-level target and the target with the app icon. For the top-level target, manually change the version and build numbers under: build settings – versioning – Current Project Version (type your build number) and Marketing Version (type your version number). For the app icon target, the build and version numbers can simply be updated under the General tab (this will automatically update the Build Settings-Versioning fields for this target). The information under the top level target is (I believe) the information that the archiving process looks for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flutter I don't recommend using the `MARKETING_VERSION` because you probably want the same version for Android and iOS. So I recommend changing the version in the `pubspec.yaml` file and then running `flutter run`.