# Error publishing app on apple, archive without version

Tags: archive

oh when I post it gives identity error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsRMg.jpg)

The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value
'' is not a valid id for the relationship 'build' (ID: 5809e44a-8b06-4ca7-83d7-bdbd4e6893d6)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IxEi.png)

tips on how to solve

Comment: I'm having the same issue uploading an already published app. It started after update to xcode 14. On Stackoverflow there a re some answer to the same issue but It's not working in my case.

Comment: same issue for me :(

Comment: hi, I update for 14.1 and problem persists

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me

[Xcode is not archiving to the specified version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73759809/xcode-is-not-archiving-to-the-specified-version-number)

```
open info.plist to source

and change this

<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
```